# TestConfiguration.ps1 error: FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine XXXX

Tags: azure-service-fabric

we have one Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance + Operations (on-premises) cluster but the self-sign certificate  is expired.
so I follow this Microsoft manual to do certificate rotation .
I cleaned up the existing environment and want to redeploy the service fabric, when I run the command ‘TestConfiguration.ps1’ to test cluster config, it get error as below, it say cannot confim FabricDataRoot system drive. but I have defined the FabricDataRoot value at clusterConfig.json.

Thanks

---

**command output:**

```
PS C:\D365Install\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.8.2.1571.9590> .\TestConfiguration.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.json


Trace folder already exists. Traces will be written to existing trace folder: C:\D365Install\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.8.2.1571.9590\DeploymentTraces
Running Best Practices Analyzer...
Opening TraceWriter SFDeployer, path C:\D365Install\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.8.2.1571.9590\DeploymentTraces\SFDeployer-637862273938616676.trace
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.5.
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.9.
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.7.
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.6.
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.11.
FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.12.
System drive for FabricDataRoot could not be confirmed for a machine in the configuration. See DeploymentTraces for details.
Best Practices Analyzer determined environment has an issue. Please see additional BPA log output in DeploymentTraces folder.
Closing TraceWriter SFDeployer, path C:\D365Install\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.8.2.1571.9590\DeploymentTraces\SFDeployer-637862273938616676.trace


LocalAdminPrivilege : True
IsJsonValid : True
IsCabValid :
RequiredPortsOpen : True
RemoteRegistryAvailable : True
FirewallAvailable : True
RpcCheckPassed : True
NoDomainController : True
NoConflictingInstallations : True
FabricInstallable : True
DataDrivesAvailable : False
DrivesEnoughAvailableSpace :
Passed : False

Test Config failed with exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Best Practices Analyzer determined environment has an issue. Please see additional BPA log output in DeploymentTraces folder.
at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
```

---

**clusterConfig.json :**

```json
"name": "Setup",
"parameters": [
{
"name": "FabricDataRoot",
"value": "C:\\SF"
},
{
"name": "FabricLogRoot",
"value": "C:\\SF\\Log"
```

---

**Trace log:**

```
2022/04/22-04:55:26.559,Verbose,3628,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,Fabric is set up on machine 192.168.99.9: False
2022/04/22-04:55:26.606,**Error**,3100,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.9.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.606,**Error**,5452,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.8.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.606,**Error**,3628,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.5.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.637,**Error**,3100,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.6.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.637,**Error**,3628,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.12.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.637,**Error**,5452,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,FabricSettings FabricDataRoot system drive could not be confirmed for machine 192.168.99.11.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.653,**Error**,5452,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,System drive for FabricDataRoot could not be confirmed for a machine in the configuration. See DeploymentTraces for details.
2022/04/22-04:55:26.653,**Error**,5452,SystemFabricDeployer.SFDeployer,Best Practices Analyzer determined environment has an issue. Please see additional BPA log output in DeploymentTraces folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Rob help reformat the question.
I had solve the problem.  that is because  anti-virus software disable computer default share. when i disable the anti-virus, the script works normal.

DataDrivesAvailable : True